# Find $ M > 0$ that for every $x > M$, we get ${{x^2 - 2x} \over {x + 2 \cos x}} >1000$

Tags: calculus

Find $ M > 0$ that for every $x > M$, we get ${{x^2 - 2x} \over {x + 2 \cos x}} >1000$

Well, the solution started like that, if $x > 2$ then:

${{x^2 - 2x} \over {x + 2 \cos x}} \ge$ ${{x(x-2)} \over {x + 2 }}  \ge $${{x(x-2)} \over {2x}} = $ ${{x \over 2} - 1} $

Then, we can choouse for e.g. $ M = 4000 $ and see that it really 'works'.

The question is, how by choosing $x > 2$ we 'eliminate' $ \cos x$, like we just did. It says here that the numerator goes donw and denominator goes up, which makes it greater or equal. but why?

> I do see that if $x > 2$ then the numerator goes up, and $x + 2 \cos x$  when $ 2 < x < 180 $ it goes down or stays the same. so why I can eliminate the $ \cos x $ like they did?

Also, I believe there's another way with domains. but I'd like to get an explanation about the way here, it looks interesting and simple.

Comment: If $x$ is large, the function in the lhs is almost $(x-2)$. In any manner $\cos(x)$ is upper and lower bounded. Use this.

Comment: To elaborate on what Claude said, the minimum of $2\cos(x)$ is $-2$ & $\frac{x^2-2x}{x-2}\geq\frac{x(x-2)}{x+2}$ holds for all $x\geq0$

Comment: @oliveeuler You mean, it holds for all $x > 2$

Comment: I think I read somewhere that $2>0$ :)

Comment: but not equal to. @oliveeuler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If me make sure $x>2$ (which we can do by choosing an $M>2$), the numerator $x(x-2)$ will stay positive.

In the denominator, we have a $2\cos x$ term which will oscillate between $-2$ and $2$.

Thus $x+2\ge x+2\cos x$.

Since both the expressions in this inequality are positive ($x+2\cos x> 2 + (-2)=0$), their inverses satisfy the following: $\dfrac1{x+2\cos x}\ge\dfrac1{x+2}$.

Now multiply by the positive term $x(x-2)$ and you obtain your inequality.

Comment: Brilliant explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

$x+2\ge x+2\cos x$ always, and when $x>2$ we know that $x>-2\cos x$, so that $x+2\cos x>0$ then this means:

$${1\over x+2\cos x}\ge {1\over x+2}$$

and then multiplying both sides by $x^2-2x$, which is also positive when $x>2$ gives you the inequality

$${x^2-2x\over x+2\cos x}\ge {x^2-2x\over x+2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Choose any $M > 2002$. Then if $x > M$, then $x^2 - 2x > \dfrac{x^2}{2}$, and $0 <x + 2cosx \leq x + 2$. Thus:

$\dfrac{x^2 - 2x}{x + 2cosx} \geq \dfrac{x^2}{2x + 4} = \dfrac{1}{2}\cdot \big(x-2 + \dfrac{4}{x+2}\big) > \dfrac{x-2}{2} > \dfrac{M -2}{2} > 1000$

Comment: I think that any $M \gt 1002$ could be sufficient.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Just checked out, $M \ge 2001$. Can't be lower than that.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS. You have equality for $x=1001.08$, then $M \geq 1002$.